# Magento 2.x - Countries are not shown when ordering

Tags: php, magento, checkout, magento2, countries

Im not that skilled in Magento and I tried to find online a solution for the next problem:

On www.drinkpackaging.eu (sorry, most of it is dutch. Its getting translated next month), people can ordering some products from me. But the problem is when you want to pay (or register).

The countries are not shown, but in Magento backhand settings all countries are selected. Anyone known with this problem or how to fix it? The shop is now useless...

However, www.snackpackaging.eu, there is the same shop and it works. Is it possible because i made more shop views etc..? Because after that I think it didnt work anymore. But im not sure.

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks a lot.

B.R.

Jurgen

Comment: Have you checked with different stores?

Comment: Hi @NiravJoshi, i checked all stores and views. But still no country that is shown. I dont know how i can compare both shops, i dont know what file i need to compare... You have any idea?